# Error compiling flex (the lexical analyzer)

Tags: flex-lexer, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to install flex (the lexical analyzer, not the Adobe program) on my Windows computer. I have MSYS installed. I untar flex, ./configure it, but when I try to make it, I get this error:

```
In file included from ccl.c:34:
flexdef.h:94:19: error: regex.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ccl.c:34:
flexdef.h:1195: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'regex_linedir'
flexdef.h:1197: error: expected ')' before '*' token
flexdef.h:1198: error: expected ')' before '*' token
flexdef.h:1199: error: expected ')' before '*' token
flexdef.h:1200: error: expected ')' before '*' token
flexdef.h:1201: error: expected ')' before '*' token
flexdef.h:1202: error: expected ')' before '*' token
make[2]: *** [ccl.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Until recently, I've only ever installed things using an .exe, so I'm pretty confused by this. Installing bison and m4 both went smoothly, and I'm wondering why this isn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you referring to "Adobe Flex" or the "Fast Lexical Analyzer (flex)" projects? If it's the former, you've got the wrong code. If it's the later, you shouldn't use the 'flex' tag since most people will understand that to reference Adobe Flex.

Comment: Flex as in the latter. I'll untag it as flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the regex library, install it and try again.

Comment: Where do I install that to relative to the flex directory?

Comment: What is "the regex library"? Will any regular expression engine suffice or is there a specific one required?

Comment: It's the gnu regex library - http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html